# How to add classes checked by user in a Wizard to project template?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsix, project-template

I'm developing an extension for Visual Studio and the goal is to allow the user to select classes through a TreeView and after clicking the Ok button the project is generated with the selected classes.
These classes are loaded by reflection from assemblies that are in a specific folder.
So I can load the assemblies and through a TreeView the user can select the classes that he wants.
The point is how to put these classes in a collection and create the folder structure and classes in the generated project template. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

My solution has 2 projects: A wizard and the Template:

**My Solution:** [image]

**TreeView:**  [image: TreeView]

And my Wizard implementation:

```
using EnvDTE;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard;
using Primavera.Extensibility.Wizard.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Primavera.Extensibility.Wizard
{
    public class WizardImplementation : IWizard
    {
        private Modules frm;

        // This method is called before opening any item that   
        // has the OpenInEditor attribute.  
        public void BeforeOpeningFile(ProjectItem projectItem)
        {
        }

        public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
        {
        }

        // This method is only called for item templates,  
        // not for project templates.  
        public void ProjectItemFinishedGenerating(ProjectItem
            projectItem)
        {
        }

        // This method is called after the project is created.  
        public void RunFinished()
        {
        }

        public void RunStarted(object automationObject,
            Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary,
            WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
        {
            try
            {
                // Display a form to the user. The form collects the classes checked 
                frm = new Modules();
                frm.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        // This method is only called for item templates,  
        // not for project templates.  
        public bool ShouldAddProjectItem(string filePath)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```